# Google Font doesn't work locally on IE

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have decided to use one of the google fonts on my website.  Part of that is I wish to download the font and put it on my server as oppose to relying on google every time my page is loaded.  So to implement a google font all you need is this:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I threw that up on a test page and it works great in all browsers and ie9 and up.  Then I tried to copy that code into my css as oppose to have it hosted by google, here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tt77hLor/

You will see that the fiddle uses the new font if you open in chrome, but in IE 11 it does not.  According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff2 woff2 is not supported by IE which explains why it doesn't work, but then why does it work if I throw in that link and how can I download that to my server so that I don't have to rely on google?

EDIT:

I got my question answered in the comments, I wish somebody posted it so I can mark correct.  Since I can't, I will alter the question slightly.  The reason to my original question is that google serves you a different css file depending on what browser you are from.  To alter my question:

Is this the correct way to replicate such on a local server:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src:  url('Roboto Condensed Cyrillic Ext.eot');
  src:  local('Roboto Condensed Light'), 
    local('RobotoCondensed-Light'),
    url('Roboto Condensed Cyrillic Ext.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('Roboto Condensed Cyrillic Ext.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('Roboto Condensed Cyrillic Ext.woff') format('woff'),
    url('Roboto Condensed Cyrillic Ext.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('Roboto Condensed Cyrillic Ext.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
```

Should that local come before the first src?

Comment: your `@font-face` doesn't have the necessary fallbacks for IE. IE usually relies on [.eot](http://caniuse.com/#search=eot). See [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) for the fallback syntax I am talking about

Comment: Google [returns a different stylesheet](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/technical_considerations#what_is_the_google_fonts_api_serving) at that address depending on the browser requesting it. For IE it returns one referencing an EOT (Embedded OpenType) file instead of a WOFF.

Comment: yeah @hobbs is correct. Hit `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300` for yourself in IE and you will get a different stylesheet

Comment: @hobbs That could be a fine answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol considered it, but I'm not willing to make it one without some advice on what to do :)

Comment: Just use the squirrel-standard way of including fonts.

Comment: One of the issues I am seeing is that when you open the link in chrome you get support for latin, cirillic, etc.., but if I open ie I get WOFF and it only has the base english characters.

Comment: @hobbs I updated my question, can you post an answer now so I can mark it correct, seeing how you gave me the original answer?